# Unity Netcode for Game Objects host won't load host

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a multiplayer game setup, but I want to let players host local clients. For some reason when I launch as a host, an instance of my player isn't created like when making a client to join the dedicated server. I am getting no error msgs or anything that would indicate it is a syntax issue.

```cs
public class sceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private NetworkManager network;
    [SerializeField] private UnityTransport transport; 

    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }

    public void LoadClient()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("TestScene");
        transport.SetConnectionData("my-ip", 8089);
        network.StartClient();
    }

    public void LoadServer()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("TestScene");
        network.StartServer();
    }

    public void LoadHost()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("TestScene");
        transport.SetConnectionData("127.0.0.1", 7777);
        network.StartHost();
    }
}
```

Comment: What multiplayer service are you using?

Comment: Unity Transport. I think that is what you're asking?

Comment: Yes thanks. Unfortunately I don’t use it and I can’t help. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your player prefab to the network managers player prefab field and than start the host by accessing the singleton instance. This player prefab attached get spawned automatically.

```
NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();
```

In general you can access the singleton instance for all of your desired tasks.

```
public void StartHost()
{
    NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();
    NetworkManager.Singleton.SceneManager.LoadScene("your scene", LoadSceneMode.Single);
}

public void StartClient()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(IpInput.text)) return;
    NetworkManager.Singleton.GetComponent<UnityTransport>().SetConnectionData("your ip", 1234);
    NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();
}
```